# Golang - Why can I invoke a pointer receiver method from a value type?

Tags: function, pointers, methods, go

I am going through the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/list) again, and I am confused by this [Methods Module](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4)

In short a type `Vertex` is specified as well as a function with a pointer receiver

```
type Vertex struct {
  X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Scale(f float64) {
  v.X = v.X * f
  v.Y = v.Y * f
}
```

No worries here. However, my confusion comes from the main function which appears to allow a value type to invoke a method which specifies a pointer receiver.

```
func main() {
  v := Vertex{3, 4}
  v.Scale(10)
  // v's fields have changed
}
```

I checked the type of v just to make sure

```
fmt.Printf("v's type is %T\n", v)
// v's type is main.Vertex
```

Why is this allowed? Shouldn't `v` need to be a pointer to invoke the `Scale` method e.g. `v := &Vertex{3, 4}`

Comment: You have the answer a few slides after: https://tour.golang.org/methods/6

Comment: @T.Claverie, I had just seen that and was posting it as an answer, lol!

Comment: It is allowed because the language spec says so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same tutorial, an explanation is provided a few slides later:

In the [Methods and pointer indirection slide](https://tour.golang.org/methods/6), the following excerpt provides an explanation:

> For the statement v.Scale(10), even though v is a value and not a pointer, the method with the pointer receiver is called automatically. That is, as a convenience, Go interprets the statement v.Scale(10) as (&v).Scale(10) since the Scale method has a pointer receiver.